# C++ Boost Asio: How do I have multiple clients?

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

How can I have multiple connections over a single port in boost asio?

Do I need to have a socket for each client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a new connection is accepted, a new socket will be created for it, you don't have to create sockets yourself. Have you checked the examples in the manual? Like the chat-server, I think it handles multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

Make a vector of asio socket*. Then work with that.For each client you want to accept push back a new socket.Hope this work!!